# Copying a file directly from a client's computer to the server folder

Tags: php, ajax, file, upload

I am using ajax to upload a picture from the user's computer to my folder whenever he/she selects a photo from the file dialog?

Can `move_uploaded_file()` work up here? I don't think so. :)

Comment: Please show some code - how do you do the upload? How do you handle it?

Comment: you cant upload files with AJAX.

Comment: No. your server can NOT reach out to the user's computer and suck out a file directly. There's virtually NO ONE out there that isn't behind a firewall that would block such an attempted outright. Even if they're not firewalled, they're probably still behind NAT gateways, VPNs, etc... and not reachable by your server. e.g. there's probably about 1 uncommon network configuration where it MIGHT work, and far too many very common configurations that make it impossible.

Comment: @davidkonrad, yes you can, with XmlHttpRequest2 FormData feature! Of course one should take care about [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=formdata) before using this.

Comment: @samuel, you are completely right XHR2. upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to do file uploader with ajax - it is extremely easy to do this with [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). It gives you a lot of functionality like drag and drop/preview/deletion and many more right from the box

Back to your question:

Why do you think it would not?

You have to do something like this

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      }
    }
  } else {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Please read all the thing from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) and from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

P.S file uploading is a really tricky question. It is easy to implement it, but to implement it insecurely. In order to do things in a right way - please consider reading this security topics

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29719/secure-php-upload-form-storage?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php), if its not uploaded and you have access to client computer...

Example of use:

```
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
```

Or use xcopy like this:

```
exec('xcopy c:\\myfolder d:\\myfolder /e/i', $a, $a1);
```

Assuming you have full access

Comment: What do you mean by access?

Comment: You did not specify how the data are handled, if they are uploaded by the script you can use `move_uploaded_file()`, if not you need access to clients computer (ftp or semothing) and just use copy or xcopy as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (move_uploaded_file($source, $target)) {
}
```